# Why Mohr's salt and not FeSO4 in titration?

Tags: redox, titration

During titration of $\ce{KMnO4}$, we use Mohr's salt instead of ferrous sulphate salt to prepare the standard salt solution. Is it done to prevent oxidation of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ to $\ce{Fe^3+}$ before the titration itself? But to prevent that sulphuric acid is used. So why we do not use ferrous sulphate salt instead?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_iron(II)_sulfate#Applications

Comment: To put an answer, and prevent link rot, quoting Wikipedia with my emphasis, "Mohr's salt is the preferred source of ferrous ions as the **solid has a long shelf life, being resistant to oxidation.** This stability extends somewhat to solutions reflecting the effect of pH on the ferrous/ferric redox couple. This oxidation occurs more readily at high pH. ***The ammonium ions make solutions of Mohr's salt slightly acidic, which slows this oxidation process***"